# Keeping Windows Command Line in (cci)

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have tried posting this to Salesforce Stack Exchange however it was removed for being off-topic. I suppose it is more of a Windows question.

I am using Cumulus CI to create scratch orgs in Salesforce. We have a requirement to create multiple scratch orgs so I wanted to use a batch file to do this. Usually after running activate.ps1 my command line looks like below:

```
(cci) C:\Users\CurrentUser>
```

The problem is when running from a .bat the `(cci)` part disappears on the next command meaning none of my cci commands are valid. Here's my .bat:

```
cd C:\Users\CurrentUser\workspace\trainingenv
set /p amount="Enter amount of scratch orgs to create: "
set /A result=%amount%-1
start /B C:\Python27\venvs\cci\Scripts\activate
for %%x in (1,1,%amount%) do cci org scratch dev test%%x
pause
```

The last command before pause should run in the cci mode but it doesn't. However when the script ends and I press enter after the final pause I am back in cci mode. Is there a way to get cmd line to stay in cci mode? When I run the above .bat this is the error I get:

```
cci org scratch dev test1
'cci' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I hope this is clear enough. I'm not sure on the terminology as I am very new to this but I hope it is clear what my problem is. Below is the entire output when trying to run:

```
C:\Users\LukeBray\OneDrive\Documents\Work Related Stuff\Enclude\Scratch 
Orgs>cd C:\Users\LukeBray\workspace\trainingenv

C:\Users\LukeBray\workspace\trainingenv>set /p amount="Enter amount of 
scratch orgs to create: "
Enter amount of scratch orgs to create: 2

C:\Users\LukeBray\workspace\trainingenv>set /A result=2-1

C:\Users\LukeBray\workspace\trainingenv>start /B 
C:\Python27\venvs\cci\Scripts\activate

C:\Users\LukeBray\workspace\trainingenv>for %x in (1 1 2) do cci org scratch 
dev test%x

C:\Users\LukeBray\workspace\trainingenv>cci org scratch dev test1
'cci' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\LukeBray\workspace\trainingenv>cci org scratch dev test1
'cci' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\LukeBray\workspace\trainingenv>cci org scratch dev test2
'cci' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\LukeBray\workspace\trainingenv>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
(cci) C:\Users\LukeBray\workspace\trainingenv>
```

Comment: If `cci` is not located in the current working directory it needs to know where it is.  Give it the full path to the executable.

Comment: @Squashman, the file for the `cci` command is likely in the "C:\Python27\venvs\cci\Scripts" directory, which should be in `PATH` after running the virtual environment's activate.bat. But using `start /b` for this is odd. Try `call C:\Python27\venvs\cci\Scripts\activate.bat`.

Comment: Yes, the file is in the "C:\Python27..." directory. I had used `start /b`because I didn't know how to call an executable without it running in a new command window. `call`doesn't seem to run anything. The command window just hangs for a bit after I call the .bat and then proceeds to the `pause` command

Comment: `call` executes the target batch script in the current CMD shell and then returns to the calling script. Without it, running another batch script doesn't return to the caller. So after `call "C:\Python27\venvs\cci\Scripts\activate.bat"`, the `for` loop will run and then `pause`. This is the correct way to activate the virtual environment.